# Help identifying proper transistor MOSFET

Tags: transistors, mosfet

Hoping to get a bit of help when it comes to replacing some blown MOSFETs on my pure sine wave inverter (model number HP12048D).

They're listed as IRFB4110, which I can find pretty easily, but it's the second line I'm not sure I need to pay attention to.

These are P921D, but I find a bunch of different second-line codes and am not sure if they'll work for this application.

For example, I see a P8251, P352Y, 024P and a few others, but not having much luck finding P921Ds.

Does this secondary line matter?

[image: Blown Mosfets]

Comment: Nope that's factory and date code  but try to get them all the same or get extra and sort them by Vgs=Vds with some small current

Comment: Big question is: why did this fail, and why replacing the mosfets is supposed to fix the underlying problem? Inverters are supposed to be overload- and overtemperature-protected. The mosfets are blown, sure, but you must identify *why* they are blown. In all likelihood you'll replace the mosfets and just blow the new ones again...

Comment: @Kubahasn'tforgottenMonica what an optimist, you are. The quality of these things vary a lot. They also usually suffer mechanical stress.

Comment: @Kubahasn'tforgottenMonica Hardware issue caused grid and battery power to go through it at the same time and blew it up.
I've resolved the hardware issue that caused that to happen and have to repair the inverter now.
(Contactor for grid power got stuck open and when the inverter tried to switch back to batteries... Well... Yeah)

Answer (score 5):

The first place to look for this kind of information is always the datasheet. It's not always there, but often it is. We know that IR was acquired by Infineon, so the primary datasheet source is https://www.infineon.com. And [here](https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/Infineon-IRFB4110-DataSheet-v01_01-EN.pdf) it is.

[image]

Your MOSFETs are the first option of markings, lead-free made in the 21st week of some year ending in a '9', and the rest relates to where they were assembled and lot codes.

Comment: Thank you very much for the info and explaining it thoroughly, I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

These need to be matched Vgs=Vds by testing with R to V+.

This is to prevent thermal runaway from NTC and Vgs mismatch.

Comment: This is not very critical for MOSFETs due to the positive tempco of RdsON, especially when used for switching with Vgs much higher than gate threshold voltage.

Comment: @PStechPaul . I believe your comment is not true for linear mode used in true sine inverters.  This is because the NTC of Vgs dominates which FET turns on 1st during zero crossing when all shunted together. in BJT's an Re is added for this reason , just enough to prevent runaway.  The NTC effect on Vgs/Id is greater than the PTC effect on RdsRdsOn for slow linear sine but not for fast pseudo-sine and PWM as switches.. Can you see the failure mode is thermal runaway from the heat marks and explosive results that cascaded to many FET's blowing open before fusing?

Comment: I could be wrong and if HP made a clever design to sense current and with Vgs error feedback to accelerate the Vgs bipolar transition out of saturation with enough cross-conduction to normalize the RdsOn of all FETs on each polarity, so that the thermal drift range of PTC, is self-limiting the power dissipation to be shared equally.

Answer (score 0):

the metal tabs on the blown mosfets are not the correct shape, they're fakes.

the tabs should have a half hole like the diagram above, but the hole should also be ever so slightly elongated at the bottom,put two together its almost starting to form a heart shape.

also check the font, genuine ones the B isnt fully formed it is made of an I and a 3 almost, same with the R

i just had 30 'genuine' arrive today that were recycled/pulled from equipment, i have 12 genuine, 12 that are from IR but the font is wrong so they have been sanded blank and remarked but with wrong logo and wrong font, and 4 not IR produced at all but some random clone of unknown spec.

Comment: The tab being shaped differently isn't great evidence that they're fake. IR/Infineon probably doesn't have just one source of leadframes.

Comment: well ive yet to see a respected supplier (ie mouser/digikey/farnells) show them without the curved ears to the tab, and none of the data sheets show square cut outs so the only time i have seen that is when the supplier has been smaller sites. also IRFB isnt FB so i guess theres lots of "good" FB4110, I wouldnt use them, theres only one manufacture of IRFB4110, FB4110 on the other hand are just well, copies, and can be good or bad. i'll still call them fakes and not use them so i know what I am using is to spec